# How to securely pass the API Key in the HTTP Header?

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, api-design

I am building a API suite to connect to our application. Each user will have an unique API key which will be passed in the Header.

I am here to ask, what is the best way to authenticate the user? I donot want the user to pass the API key without any encryption ?

I am passing the API key like this :

```
$headers['x-axpr-auth'] = '<API-KEY>';
```

Since, I am building the API myself, I have the flexibility to use different encryption/authentication techniques.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against?  If you're using HTTPS (which you should be), you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 4):

Using HTTPS is pretty much mandatory in this case so I'm going to assume you (will) do that.

If you have an API key with long-term validity, then you should consider using some kind of "temporary token" with (very?) limited validity - so the attack window is much smaller.
This is similar to using Basic Authentication (sending password with every request) versus sending credentials only once and using session cookie afterward.

You should look at existing authentication/authorization schemes - OAuth2 (with access and refresh tokens) may be relevant since you're building APIs. OpenID Connect builds on top of OAuth2 and provides a proper authentication layer.

Apart from that, it's uncommon to explicitly encrypt API token in an HTTP header, since the whole communication is already encrypted using HTTPS.